# Can't set on click listener to an element in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

I have this issue where whenever I try to interact with an element in Kotlin I just can't select it the way I was doing before. For example if I had a `button` in my XML with an ID of `button` I would just do this from Kotlin:

```kotlin
button.setOnClickListener {
   ...
}
```

But now this simply does not work and I don't know the reason why...
Here is my `MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.awaitResponse

const val BASE_URL = "https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var TAG = "MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getCurrentData()
    }

    private fun getCurrentData() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .create(ApiRequests::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.getFacts().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.text)

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gen_new_fact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:text="Generate Another Fact"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am running the latest stable version of Android Studio 4 on Windows 10

Comment: Read this: https://medium.com/better-programming/why-are-kotlin-synthetics-deprecated-and-what-are-the-alternatives-5c2b087dda1c

Comment: So It's deprecated now?

Comment: Yes it is deprecated.

Comment: Oof, thank you! You saved me. But I don't understand why :(

Comment: I had the same issue with kotlin synthetics. I was accessing a view that was nested in other views. Kept getting NPE. The solution was to access the view through the whole chain of views. So, if you want to access view3 which is nested like this view1->view2->view3, then you would need to access it like this: view1.view2.view3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to your button in your code. An example would be using `findViewById` to get a reference to the Button in your Kotlin code. It could look like this:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.gen_new_fact);
button.setOnClickListener {
  // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just found out that Kotlin Synthetics have been deprecated. I will use this as a workaround. Thank you Again!

Comment: It's not a workaround, this is the normal way to do it! Synthetics were just a "magic code" way to bind views to variables automatically, and it's deprecated because the ``ViewBinding`` library is the recommended way to do this automatic stuff (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). You basically inflate a binding class (like in the example) and then the resulting object (usually named ``binding`` in examples) has all your view references, like ``binding.button``